# What are the alternative ways to manipulate camera raw files in PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing, dng

I'm re-coding my personal photo blog and want to upload and manipulate photos on site.

I know that Imagick ( [Convert RAW photos to JPEG in linux/php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558487/convert-raw-photos-to-jpeg-in-linux-php) ) is an option but I'm wondering if there are any other options out there which enables PHP to manipulate and convert camera raw images (crw, dng etc.)?

Comment: If I would word an answer to your question, the answer would be "Probably maybe". Would you accept such an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need best RAW functionality, use open source command line utility [dcraw](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/).

Many linux RAW tools are using it too.