# Converting RAW to JPEG (attempting to use) ImageMagick

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

**I do not care if a solution that converts RAW to JPEGs uses ImageMagick or not, it just appeared to be the most doucmented, so I started there.**

I have had success converting a JPEG to a different sized JPEG, but have been unable to convert a RAW to a JPEG.  After looking at [Convert RAW photos to JPEG in linux/php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558487/convert-raw-photos-to-jpeg-in-linux-php), I tried that code:

```
try {
    $im = new Imagick($inputURL);
    $im->setimageformat("jpg");
    $im->writeimage($outputURL);
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

and received this error:

```
exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `/tmp/magick-XXaana6Q.ppm': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2480' in /UPSTREAM/public_html/core/functions.php:116 Stack trace: #0 /UPSTREAM/public_html/core/functions.php(116): Imagick->__construct('/UPSTREAM/p...') #1 /UPSTREAM/public_html/core/functions.php(129): resizeImage('/UPSTREAM/p...', '/UPSTREAM/p...', Array) #2 {main}
```

I then tried:

```
exec("/usr/bin/convert -define jpeg:size=1280x720 {$inputURL} {$outputURL}");
```

based on the same post near the bottom, but it is not producing any file.

Then I tried [raw to JPEG conversion](http://www.wizards-toolkit.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20995), but I haven't had any luck with that code either.  Then I modified it with [Convert PDF to JPEG with PHP and ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227014/convert-pdf-to-jpeg-with-php-and-imagemagick) to no avail (**EDIT:** I got a similar error to the one above):

```
try {
    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->setResolution(300,300);
    $im->readimage($inputURL); 
    $im->setimageformat("jpg");
    $im->writeimage($outputURL);
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

For kicks, these are variations that I've tried:

```
//echo "/usr/bin/convert {$inputURL} -resize {$dimensions[0]}x{$dimensions[1]} {$outputURL}";
#phpinfo();
#exec("/usr/bin/convert {$inputURL} -resize {$dimensions[0]}x{$dimensions[1]} {$outputURL}");
#exec("/usr/bin/convert {$inputURL} -define {$dimensions[0]}x{$dimensions[1]} {$outputURL}");
#exec("/usr/bin/convert -resize {$dimensions[0]}x{$dimensions[1]} rgb:{$inputURL} {$outputURL}");
#exec("/usr/bin/convert -define jpeg:size=1280x720 {$inputURL} {$outputURL}");
```

**(Potentially) Pertinent Details:**

- I am using WebHostingHub as my host so the `/usr/bin/convert` is their equivalent to the `convert`.
- **(EDIT)** I am using a Sony camera, such that all of my RAW files will contain a `.ARW` extension

Comment: for a start there are mulitple raw formats